# Best practices for returning a Color.FromArgb when given an int that may be null C#

Tags: c#, entity-framework, int, nullable, system.drawing.color

I was just curious what a best practices solution would be given my current situation. I have a database storing colors in ARGB integer form, but I allow it to be nullable since sometimes the color may not need to be specified. Using the Entity Framework, I have a generated class with a ColorArgb property for accessing that column that returns and int, as expected. I've also manually added another property, Color, that returns a System.Drawing.Color object. The Color property is pretty much just a go between so I can interact with the generated class in a more natural fashion. Setting is as simple as:

```
ColorArgb = value.ToArgb();
```

However, getting is a little more interesting. Here's what I have so far:

```
return ColorArgb == null ? Color.Empty : Color.FromArgb(ColorArgb ?? 0);
```

As you can see, I want to maintain the idea that a Color is not necessary for this class, so I return Color.Empty when the underlying ARGB value is null, but the right hand side of the null coalescing operator is never reached. I have guaranteed that the value is not null, but I don't know how to explicitly tell the compiler in a best practices form. Not a serious issue, but I would like to learn. As such, all help is greatly appreciated.

Edit: ColorArgb is of type `System.Nullable<int>`

Comment: Is `ColorArgb` of type `int?`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to use the null coalescing operator if you know that the value is not null. Instead use `ColorArgb.Value`:

```
return ColorArgb == null ? Color.Empty : Color.FromArgb(ColorArgb.Value);
```

Comment: Simple. Perfect. Thanks a million.
Will mark as answer as soon as possible.

Comment: Actually, if you want to optimize away the check if the value is null, you should use `ColorArgb.GetValueOrDefault()` as `ColorArgb.Value` will again check if it is null internally, but `GetValueOrDefault` will simply return the internal field directly. I doubt this will be even measurably different though.

Answer (score 2):

More cleaner approach could be like this if you need black color for zero integer value.

```
    return Color.FromArgb(ColorArgb.GetValueOrDefault());
```

Otherwise to check nullable integer you should check .HasValue Property instead of null comparison like this.

```
    return ColorArgb.HasValue ? Color.FromArgb(ColorArgb.Value) : Color.Empty;
```

Comment: Thank you for your response! I just did some digging and found out that the null comparison is compiled into a call to `.HasValue`. Still appreciate the different perspective.